# Distinguishing between types of GMM

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

GMM is an abbreviation for

- Generalized Method of Moments
- Gaussian Mixture Models
- Growth Mixture Models

The second usage seems to be far more common on CV, but now that Lars Hansen has finally won a Nobel, would it be possible to somehow separate out the GMM questions? At the very least, it makes it hard to search.

Comment: Maybe you can give a start by: i) creating a different tag from gmm, and ii) editing the excerpt and tag wiki in both tags to remove ambiguity. This would help with the future.

Comment: For a more general version of this topic, see [here](http://meta.stats.stackexchange.com/questions/1707/is-it-reasonable-to-put-try-to-avoid-acronyms-in-the-help-on-asking-questions)

Comment: I created a new tag for gmm. It also looks like there's an older [generalized moments tag](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/generalized-moments/synonyms), but I can't add gmm as synonym since I don't have enough points on that tag.

Comment: I also think that usage is [rare](https://books.google.com/ngrams/interactive_chart?content=generalized+moments%2Cgeneralized+method+of+moments%2Cgaussian+mixture+model&year_start=1900&year_end=2001&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cgeneralized%20moments%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cgeneralized%20method%20of%20moments%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cgaussian%20mixture%20model%3B%2Cc0), so perhaps the generalized moments tag should be retired.

Comment: I've suggested gmm as synonym for generalized moments. I think both of the tags should be synonyms. Questions about GMM are rare, but so are question on econometrics. I wonder maybe generalized-moments tag came from economics.SE, when it was merged to crossvalidated.com?

Comment: See here for previous discusion, [Should the gmm tag be added?](http://meta.stats.stackexchange.com/q/1564/1036)

Answer (score 9):

Ah, not again!

Dimitriy, I did some work a few months ago of weeding out the generic `gmm` tag, and separating it into `generalized-moments` (`generalized-method-of-moments` was too long), `gaussian-mixture` for the classification/machine learning folks, and `growth-mixture-model` (which is what psychologists and education researchers think when they hear GMM). I think I kept the `gmm` wiki entry saying that the use of this tag is confusing and discouraged, in favor of these three specific ones, but since no questions were tagged `gmm` after my overhaul, it disappeared. Your... uhm... help in re-establishing `gmm` is... uhm... appreciated, but it would be much better if you folded the `gmm` description into `generalized-moments`.

Moderators: is there any way to protect a tag even if there are no entries for it?

Comment: The tag can be banned forever, but it would be best if it is simply turned into a synonym.

Comment: The problem with turning it into a synonym @gung is that the GMM acronym can't be differentiated between several different types of statistical analysis. I'd prefer *not* to (by default) choose one of those options as a synonym given the ambiguity.

Comment: @gung, there has to be a disambiguation, something along the lines of "Please do not use `gmm` tag. Instead, use the `generalized-moments` for GMM in econometrics; `gaussian-mixutre` for GMM in machine learning and classification; and `growth-mixture-model` for GMM in psychology."

Comment: I would suggest to clear the [tag:gmm] tag and refer in the About section to the three other tags, as suggested by Stas. Also, 'generalized-method-of-moments' cannot be recorded as a synonym for [tag:generalized-moments] (too many characters), but a moderator can easily discard the 'gmm' <-> 'generalized-moments' association that was suggested recently.

Comment: I've folded in the description of GMM that Dimitriy provided into `generalized-moments` tag, and wrote a strong language in `gmm` tag to discourage users from actually using it.

Comment: Thanks, Stas! I think it should be clear now.